# How to solve the linker 'Error: L6218E Undefined symbol' when I compile a project with RTOS ThreadX?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, keil, rtos, linker

I'm trying to compile a project where I have add the Software Pack `RTOS ThreadX` on a STM32F4 and I'm using uVision Keil 5.29.
I have included ThreadX in the project by CubeMX (option `Select Components` of the Menù `Software Packs`).

When I compile the project created by CubeMX (I have not modified anything) the linker give the following 3 errors:

```
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol __RAM_segment_used_end__ (referred from tx_initialization_low_level.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol _vectors (referred from tx_initialization_low_level.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol g_pfnVectors (referred from tx_initialization_low_level.o).
```

This means that the 3 symbols are not defined. All the symbols are used in the object file `tx_initialization_low_level.o`.
**Note.** The assemmbler module `tx_initialization_low_level.s` has been inserted in the project by `RTOS ThreadX`.

How can I define the 3 symbols (`__RAM_segment_used_end__`, `_vectors`, `g_pfnVectors`) to solve these errors?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this thread](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001EgVbFSAV/azure-rtos-mdkarm-linking-errors) on the ST forums?

Comment: Yes but in this moment I can't reinstall the Keil environment so I'm looking for an other solution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use Keil, but I'd be surprised if you couldn't simply just update the compiler/toolchain.

Comment: @Velvel Ok when it will be possible I'll try to update the Keil toolchain and I hope that the information contained in [this link](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001EgVbFSAV/azure-rtos-mdkarm-linking-errors) are correct.